# SpriteKit Racing top down Game

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, game-engine

I want to write a simple top down racing game for iOS. I want to use Sprite Kit instead Cocos2D , I'm new to game development and I have a question:

How can I create the race tracks? What I think is: One single big background image for each track and a car that moves over it and remains inside the track by interaction with a path. The path is inserted by a coordinate system in the level code and represents the "borders" of the road.

Is this a good way to start a top down racing game? Or are there better ways? How can I "draw" the path over my background image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "Tiled Map Editor" http://www.mapeditor.org/ to create your maps.  I'm thinking you'll only need a few unique tiles, one for straight track, one for grass, one for curved track, maybe some trees, etc.

As for the path, you can try to use an polygonal edge physics body? And then move the car to where the user touches on the screen.  if the user tries to move the car outside, the car will bump against the physics body of the edge.